# Creating Callables using Annotation

Tags: java, annotations, apt

I'm attempting to make a system similar to https://github.com/ElgarL/TownyChat/blob/master/src/com/palmergames/bukkit/TownyChat/TownyChatFormatter.java

```
replacer.registerFormatReplacement(Pattern.quote("{worldname}"), new TownyChatReplacerCallable() {
        @Override
        public String call(String match, LocalTownyChatEvent event) throws Exception {
            return String.format(ChatSettings.getWorldTag(), event.getEvent().getPlayer().getWorld().getName());
        }
    });
    replacer.registerFormatReplacement(Pattern.quote("{town}"), new TownyChatReplacerCallable() {
        @Override
        public String call(String match, LocalTownyChatEvent event) throws Exception {
            return event.getResident().hasTown() ? event.getResident().getTown().getName() : "";
        }
    });
```

and more.

Is there a way to use annotations to cut down on the amount of repeated code, avoiding reflection to call the call method, and only using it during registration, if at all?

I'm not adverse to the idea of creating an annotation pre processor as I was already planning on doing this to enable automatically generating documentation.

Comment: You could have a class with lots of methods like `@PatternHandler("foo") String someMethodName(String match, LocalTownyChatEvent event) {}` which are registered via that annotation and you would save the `replacer.registerFormatReplacement(` part. Would either need reflection to register each as a `Method` or you'd need to make each a `Callable`

Comment: This was sort of what I had in mind, but my problem is  "Would either need reflection to register each as a Method or you'd need to make each a Callable"

I have no idea how to start that part.

I had also planned on using an Annotation processor at some stage, to generate the documentation, so that's the main driving reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you write a small Annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@interface PatternHandler {
    String value();
}
```

And create a class like

```
class Callables {

    @PatternHandler("foo")
    public static final TownyChatReplacerCallable FOO = new TownyChatReplacerCallable() {
        @Override
        public String call(String match, String event) {
            return "This is foo handler called with " + match + "," + event;
        }
    };

    @PatternHandler("bar")
    public static final TownyChatReplacerCallable BAR = new TownyChatReplacerCallable() {
        @Override
        public String call(String match, String event) {
            return "This is foo handler called with " + match + "," + event;
        }
    };
}
```

Now you can take the whole class or even multiple classes that contain those static fields and pass it to some registry method that iterates reflectively over each field in that class and if it's an annotated callable registers that.

```
class AnnotationRegistry {
    public static void register(String pattern, TownyChatReplacerCallable handler) {}

    public static void register(Class<?> clazz) {
        // only fields declared by this class, not inherited ones (static fields can't be inherited)
        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            // must have that annotation
            PatternHandler annotation = field.getAnnotation(PatternHandler.class);
            if (annotation != null) {
                // must be static
                if (!Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) {
                    System.out.println("Field must be static:" + field.getName());
                    continue;
                }
                // get content of that field
                try {
                    Object object = field.get(null);
                    // must be != null and a callable
                    if (object instanceof TownyChatReplacerCallable) {
                        register(annotation.value(), (TownyChatReplacerCallable) object);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Field must be instanceof TownyChatReplacerCallable:"  + field.getName());
                    }
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That would save you a bit code and would have no speed disadvantage at runtime since there is no need to use reflection to call those callables.

Full example here: http://ideone.com/m3PPcY

Besides using static fields, you can also use non static ones if you pass an instance of a class to the registry which would then be used like `Object object = field.get(instance);` instead of the `null`.

Furthermore, instead of fields the same approach would work with methods which would be less code to write:

```
@PatternHandler("foo")
public static String fooMethod(String match, String event) {
    return "This is foo handler called with " + match + "," + event;
}
```

Registry would then look for all [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html)s. Then for example wrap them in

```
class MethodAdapter implements TownyChatReplacerCallable {
    private final Method method;
    public MethodAdapter(Method m) {
        method = m;
    }
    @Override
    public String call(String match, String event) {
        try {
            return (String) method.invoke(null, match, event);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "OMGZ";
        }
    }
}
```

and continue as usual. But beware: invoking a method reflectively is potentially slower than calling it directly via code - few percent only, nothing to worry about

Full example for methods: http://ideone.com/lMJsrl

Comment: Thanks, others have been telling me just to invoke the methods via reflection, but was under the impression that it should be avoided most of the time, guess these are one of the times where it actually helps.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Anything that helps you write cleaner / less code should not be avoided. There are obviously some downsides like losing a bit of the usual compile-time-type-safety since checks have to be done at runtime, [performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize), strange looking code that beginners don't understand, ... but it's IMO totally worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try new Java 8 Lambda Expressions instead (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

```
replacer.registerFormatReplacement(Pattern.quote("{worldname}"), new TownyChatReplacerCallable() {
        @Override
        public String call(String match, LocalTownyChatEvent event) throws Exception {
            return String.format(ChatSettings.getWorldTag(), event.getEvent().getPlayer().getWorld().getName());
        }
    });
```

Can be written as :

```
replacer.registerFormatReplacement(
  Pattern.quote("{worldname}"), 
  (match, event) -> { return String.format(ChatSettings.getWorldTag(), event.getEvent().getPlayer().getWorld().getName()); } 
});
```

You can also push it further with another interface, method, ... that wrap it

Comment: Unfortunately not an option. stuck on java 6.