# Reflections bad or good practice for commands

Tags: java, reflection

Well, I saw there were some questions and answers about this, but they didn't really satisfy me.

Let's say for example, I have programmed a console. It's a nice JFrame with an output and an input txtField/Area. But this console should not only be used for output, but also to run commands.

Because I would need this console very often and I don't want to change the code of the console I programmed it this way:

The console has one method to register commands.

```
console.registerCommand(String command, String methodToInvoke, Object invokeObject);
```

With this method I'm able to use this console everywhere without the need of changing or inharitance.

Whenever the `String command` is written the console knows it's a registered keyword and executes the method via reflection.

Would this be a good or bad practice? On code styling and in performance! And what could I do better?

I also found it quite neat to use reflections this way to add ActionListeners to MenuItems in a TrayIcon.

**Edit**

To the Answer below:

Ok with commands i would accept this is a way to do. But in the Tray example I wrote a TrayHelper Class which creates the TrayIcon. There I want to add MenuItems and their ActionListeners but without creating every Object myself and add them to the Tray. So I wrote Methods like this:

```
public void addMenuItem(String label, String methodToInvoke, String invokeObject);
```

This method not only executes the method when the MenuItem is clicked, but also creates the MenuItem first, adds an ActionListener to it which invokes the Method, and adds it to the TrayIcon.

So in order to use this TrayHelper I can now just write:

```
th.addMenuItem("Exit","exitMethod",this);//executes the exitMethod of
                                         //this class after Menuitem Exit
                                         //was clicked
```

I don't really see how i could do this without reflection other than to write all the Objects myself again and adding them to the Tray. Or I'm blind :)

**Edit 2**

Ok, I was blind. I just didn't realize how to do this without reflection, but it is so simple.

Especially with the Command pattern.

Because of the anonymous classes I could do it that way, and I really like the way to write code this way (I always did it with ActionListeners)

```
th.addMenuItem("Test",new Command(){
       public void execute(){
            //do stuff
       }
});
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Do you have a specific concern?  Otherwise, this is more of a discussion than a question.  You've basically invented a poor man's plugin architecture; I see nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I used the console and had the feeling that it would push down my performance. Not only the performance of the program but also of the computer. Espacially after executing the program more often (because of development, but alway one at the same time)

Comment: Worry about performance if, and when, it actually becomes a problem.  Unless you're repeatedly executing your registered commands thousands of times in a loop from the outside, I don't see how performance is ever going to be an issue.  So just make sure any loops are running *inside* the invokeObject, and you should never have a problem with performance.

Comment: You would do it without reflection by requiring an interface for the command, as Lee's answer suggests. The name of the method to invoke would always be the same: `Execute()`

Comment: But isn't it a little bit ugly to create a new class for every command? If I only would want to open a MessageBox for the user to see I'd need to create this class

Comment: You don't necessarily need new classes for each command; your existing classes can simply implement the `Command` interface.  Then you pass an instance of your class to the `registerCommand` method.

Comment: Isn't it ugly to have a seperate file folder in a real world filing cabinet for every topic. Why not just one file folder for everything? Same reasoning. Having more classes is not bad. A good IDE will generate a new class that implements an interface and has dummy methods already written in just a few moments. Having code organized is good. Fill in the code within the framework the IDE creates. Plus a parent class can create the MenuItem, add the ActionListener and add it to the TrayIcon. Shared code in a parent class rather than a utility.

Comment: You'd need to write a method to for every command in any case, wrapping it into a class is not that much more. + using the command pattern you get compile time type safe code vs everything can crash if you mistype a method name (safer with annotations maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17832381/995891).

Comment: @LeeMeador: So you advocate a new class for every command?  That *does* seem quite heavyweight, though I do see the potential decoupling benefits.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have done just that in the past with Swing. There are very few down sides and it makes things easy to work with. Occasionally you find two commands that are very much alike but subclassing will most likely work to avoid code duplication.

Comment: @Loki I can see that rewriting might be a lot of work. I never suggest anyone rewrite something that is working. But perhaps the command pattern is something that will help as you add more features. Or you might find your existing code needs refactoring if it gets hard to work with. Or use it in the next project you work on.

Comment: @LeeMeador: In C# I think you would simply hand the `registerCommand` method a `delegate` or lambda expression.  I am reminded how software patterns are often a fix for a deficiency in the language.

Comment: @RobertHarvey And in java you could use anonymous classes to do the same thing. It is easier to do that with a base class implementing the interface and holding shared code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a better way to do this. This helps to hide the action done inside a command object. As you have to change the command, you don't have to mess with your other code.

Further, you can have a lot of different commands and they can be related by inheritance or aggregation or be injected into each other as needed AND NOBODY ELSE HAS TO KNOW.

First you have an interface:

```
public interface Command {
    void execute();
}
```

Then you have your code take one of these:

```
console.registerCommand(Command command);
```

Then you write various classes that implement the interface and do something:

```
public class OneCommand implements Command {
    public void execute() {
        theObject.theMethod(theCommand); // calls what you would have with reflection
    }
}
```

This is the standard GOF Command Pattern and you can read more about it here: [LINK TO WIKIPEDIA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

Note that this pattern, along with the other GOF patterns, were published in a book in 1994. The authors collected these best practices over many software projects. That book is in its 40th printing (according to Wikipedia).

All this suggests that lots of people have found lots of reasons to use these over many pieces of softwear, over many years and in many programming languages and systems.

It doesn't mean you need to always use them but use of a tried and tested pattern will help avoid unseen pitfalls.

Comment: So you're saying that 1.  You don't leak implementation details, and 2.  You don't need reflection anymore?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't see reflection as a bad thing. If he wants to use reflection inside the `execute()` method, that would be fine by me. But keeping the code coherent has many benefits. I think making it easy to write in the first place, reducing debugging time and faster to make changes later are the main ones.